# pyqt signal not emitted when button is clicked after move to QThread

Tags: python, pyqt, signals-slots, qthread

Essentially I have a procedure, that will start upon the button click. Once I start the procedure, everything works fine, until the user input is required. However, when the user clicks the button, no 'clicked' signal is emitted. Signal is connected to slot appropriately. Button click stoped working after I moved the code to QThread.

```
class Procedure(QObject):
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent

        self.parent.button_a.clicked.connect(self.on_button_a_clicked)
        self.event = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        # started running, doing some stuff here

        # waits for button click, i.e. when button is clicked, the event is set and then you may proceed
        self.event.wait()
        # NEVER REACHES HERE

    def on_button_a_clicked(self):
        self.event.set()

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())

        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.on_start_clicked)

    def on_start_clicked(self):
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = Procedure(self)
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)

        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.thread.start()

def main():

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, I do have an indication, that the signal is connected to slot appropriately, as when in function *run()* I manually emit the signal, the button click is emulated successfully. Therefore, I presume that the issue is that button click is not registered appropriately.

```
    def run(self):
        # started running, doing some stuff here

        # following line successfully emulates the button click
        self.parent.button_a.clicked.emit()
        self.event.wait()
        # reaches here successfully
```

I also presume that this has something to do with QThread, since the issue appeared after I started to run my procedure in a QThread, but I am kind of lost in the woods here and I am not sure how to debug this issue.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `on_button_a_clicked` is going to be called *in* its own thread, but since that thread is blocked by `event.wait()` it cannot be called. Try changing to `self.parent.button_a.clicked.connect(self.event.set)`. Be aware, though, that it's not good practice to access unrelated parent's child attributes.

Comment: Your example would not work as the code I gave here is minimized example and in reality way more is happening in that function besides *self.event.set()*, but at least now I know the problem, so I might be able to figure something out.

Comment: `self.event.wait()` blocks qt event loop so `QApplication` have no chance to recieve and handle button click.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `threading.Event` you can create slot in `Procedure` and connect it directly to `button_a.clicked` and you dont need `run` at all.